# I tried to get the user input and then compare it to somthing and i got a problem

Tags: string, rust, rust-cargo

I tried to get the user input and then compare it to somthing and i got a problem :(

this is my code:

```
use std::io::stdin;

fn main() {
    let mut command = String::new();
    loop {
        stdin().read_line(&mut command).ok().expect("Failed to read line");
        if String::from("help") == &*command {
            println!("it worked!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened? What did you expect? Please edit this to include more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```rust
use std::io::stdin;

fn main() {
    let mut command = String::new();
    loop {
        stdin().read_line(&mut command).ok().expect("Failed to read line");
        if String::from("help") == command.trim_end().to_string() {
            println!("it worked!");
        }
        command.clear();
    }
}
```

Try clearing the string before you read it again in the loop. Also, read_line leaves the newline in the string, so you may want to trim the end of the string before you compare.